# Bootstrap is 1/2 working in my MVC app

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, bundle

I have the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrapui")
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="well">A well</div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span4">
                    <h2>Column one</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="span4">
                    <h2>Column two</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="span4">
                    <h2>Column three</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and my bundle looks like this:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/bootstrapui")
    .Include("~/Content/bootstrap/bootstrap.css")
    .Include("~/Content/bootstrap/bootstrap-theme.css"));
```

And this is what my display looks like:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using bootstrap version 2 or 3?

Comment: Version 3, which is apparently the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently bootstrap 3 has removed the span* class in favor of .col*.

http://blog.jetstrap.com/2013/08/bootstrap-3-grids-explained/

```
In Bootstrap 3, the .span* classes have been removed, and replaced with 
a combination of .col-* classes: .col-xs-*, .col-sm-*, .col-md-*, and.col-lg-*.
```